# How to disable Node-Inspector Notifications from Chrome

Tags: node-inspector

I started using  [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) in Chrome and now cannot turn off the notifications I said OK to the first time.

How to do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Chrome Preferences .. and

- Search for "notifications"
- Click Content Settings
- Scroll down to Notifications
- Click Manage Exceptions for that category